Firestore rule for single document
I have a Firestore database with the following rule:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;
    }
  }
}

Here is my collection:

When querying for a set of documents, I need to include the uid in the query to satisfy the rule and it works:
try await db.collection("Stocks")
    .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: user.uid) // Include the uid for passing the rule
    .getDocuments()

However, for a single document query for a document that doesn't exist in the database, it returns permission error:
let document = try await db.collection("Stocks")
    .document(stock.id) // The document does not exist in the database
    .getDocument()

if document.exists {

} else {

}


How can I define the rule for this case?

Please edit the question to show the full rule (not just the allow part, but also the match) and the query that doesn't work the way you expect for that rule.  We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves.  If the contents of the document are relevant, please also show the document.

@DougStevenson I've update the question, thank you!

Have a look at this link Read a single document and Firestore Security Rule for allowing only one document

You rule requires that the authenticated user's UID must equal the value of the uid field of the document you're trying to get.  We can't see that this is the case, so we don't know what's going to happen when the code runs.  Please edit the question with the proof that these two conditions are being met by your code and the document.  Only then will the query be allowed by the rules.  If you actually want different rules for your query, then you need to figure out what they should be and add them to your rules - we can't tell you what your requirements are here.

@DougStevenson everytime, I use try await db.collection("Collections")
.document(collection.id) // The collection exists or does not exist in the database
.getDocument(), the Firestore returns Collections/D574A827-DF6F-4040-984E-08A5EC2D9259 failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.

@DougStevenson, I believe the issue is that we don't have a whereField for querying a single record to include the uid and meet the rule. As a result, when the document with the given DocumentID doesn't exist, it fails to pass the rule. Or Firestore should return nil document (document.exists is false) instead of the permission error. However, what's confusing is why it passes for an existing document without including the uid in the request.

Please edit your question and add a screenshot of your document.

@AlexMamo, I've updated the question.

So which line throws that exception, db.collection("Stocks").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: user.uid).getDocuments() or db.collection("Stocks").document(stock.id).getDocument()?

@AlexMamo The line db.collection("Stocks").document(stock.id).getDocument()

Do you need the same rules for all documents in all collections in the database or only in the "Stocks" collection?

We still can't see that the value of stock.id matches the ID of the document you're trying to fetch, and we can't see that the currently signed in user's ID matches the uid field of the document you're trying to fetch.  Your rule will reject any query where these conditions aren't met.  I doesn't matter if you're using getDocument or getDocuments.

@DougStevenson, yeah, I’m checking whether the document exists in the database or not. This means the stock.id might or might not exist in the database. My expectation is that if the stock.id doesn't exist, Firestore should return nil or an empty result, right? Another point is that I can't pass the uid because we can't add a whereField to this query: db.collection("Stocks").document(stock.id).getDocument(). How can I pass the uid to the query?

Rule for single document should be:
allow read: if request.auth != null && 
    (request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid
        || !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(document)));

It allow to read when the document doesn't exit in the database.


My expectation is that if the stock.id doesn't exist, Firestore should return nil or an empty result, right?

No, that's not how it works.  getDocument tries to read the document fully, even if your code only goes on to check if it exists.
Security rules prevent the client from knowing anything at all about any document that doesn't specifically match the rules, otherwise it wouldn't really be secure at all.  You're getting a permission error because you're trying to get a document that doesn't match the rules, regardless of whether or not the document exists.

Thank you for your support. But "regardless of whether or not the document exists" is not correct. let document = try await db.collection("Stocks")
.document(stock.id)
.getDocument() returns a document when tock.id exists without passing the uid.

The uid comes from the requested document itself.  That's what resource.data.uid means for single-document gets.  I suggest reviewing the documentation on this under the heading "Data validation".  For queries that could return multiple documents, it becomes a requirement for a filter on the query that limits the result to documents with the given contents.  These are all things you can test using the rules simulator in the console.
